# discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: time is a required argument that is missing

Tags: python, discord.py

I have 0 clues where the argument is missing. I was making a command to tempmute a user for a small period of time and got the error in the title when running the command.

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands


class TempMute(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        client.remove_command("tempmute")
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_role("Staff")
    async def tempmute(ctx, member: discord.Member,time:int):
        muted_role=discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
        time_convert = {"s":1, "m":60, "h":3600,"d":86400}
        tempmute = int(time[0]) * time_convert[time[-1]]
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await member.add_roles(muted_role)
        embed = discord.Embed(description= f"✅ **{member.display_name}#{member.discriminator} muted successfuly**", color=discord.Color.green())
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=5)
        await asyncio.sleep(tempmute)
        await member.remove_roles(muted_role)
        
def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(TempMute(client))
```

And the error goes as follows:

```
Ignoring exception in command tempmute:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 789, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 697, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 542, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: time is a required argument that is missing.
```

Comment: Well, where are you expecting the `time` value to come from? How are you running the command, and what do you think should happen as a result? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and make it possible for us to see the problem ourselves.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I was expecting that the user would input in the command the time they want the user to be muted for (so d for days m more minutes, etc). The command is run in a command handler which I can post the top of the file as an edit opposed to being in the client file.

Comment: What did you type to trigger the command?

Comment: Also, you have to add `self` as the first arg in every method when you are in the class.

Comment: @ChesterWOV ",tempmute"

Comment: @ChesterWOV alright will do thank you

Comment: @Cherie If you don’t add any arguments after your message it will of course raise a MissingRequiredArgument